# How can I deploy my NextJS web app on FTP Servers and not lose the SSR pages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, next.js, ftp

I need to make a NextJS web app for my company, I rather do it on Next than on React because of the SEO that Next provides me.

However, we deploy websites on **FTP** Servers and I need some of the pages on the Next app to be Server Side Rendering (because it is an e-commerce site).

How can I deploy the websites on **FTP** Servers and still be able to call the NodeJS server that Next creates?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a FTP Server in the context of a static site. If you're just looking to statically render your page, you could try `next export`. Be aware that some features won't work in the exported state.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

If `next export` doesn't fit your usecase, then you must have direct access (with something like ssh) to the server and run `next build`+`next start`.

If you don't have access to ssh of the server, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks, IndevSmiles, I'll try to think what I can do. But what are other options to deploy with NextJs:

Comment: Something like vercel or netlify is the best way to deploy with NextJS. Alternatively, a vm of some sort would work.